# Passing *Request on "net/http" to function Golang

Tags: go

Is it possible to pass Request value to another function?

```
import "net/http"

func main() {
   http.HandleFunc("saySomething", Say)
}

func Say(responseW http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
   name := getName(request) // passing request value to another function
}

func getName(request someType) string {
   request.ParseForm()
   return request.Form.Get("name")
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? That would be the easiest and quickest way to find out. Just try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can 'cause `request` is a regular variable.
It's passed by pointer, so if you will change `request` in `getName` it will change in `Say` too.

```
package main

import "net/http"

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("saySomething", Say)
}

func Say(responseW http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    name := getName(request) // passing request value to another function
    println(name)
}

func getName(request *http.Request) string {
    request.ParseForm()
    return request.Form.Get("name")
}
```

See Golang tour https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1

Comment: there is an issue here, the request is being emptied after the first read.  so if I want to read the request multiple times, it going to be available for the first time only.

Comment: what do you mean exactly?